# Command substitution interpreting spaces within quotes as argument separators

Tags: bash, quoting, alias, arguments, command-substitution

I'd like an `alias` that additionally appends itself to `~/.bashrc`, *e.g.*

```
function tailias
{
    $(echo "alias $1='${*:2}'" | tee -a ~/.bashrc)
}
```

I'm using `tee` to split the command to `~/.bashrc` while leaving the stdout intact to be run by `$()`.

This works fine for aliasing one-word commands, *e.g.*

```
[/home/acheong87] tailias f g
[/home/acheong87] alias
alias f='g'
```

and I see it appended to my `~/.bashrc`. But for commands with spaces, I get

```
[/home/acheong87] tailias ll 'ls -al'
-bash: alias: -al: not found
```

It looks correct in `~/.bashrc`—

```
alias ll='ls -al'
```

—but in the alias list I get this crazy thing:

```
[/home/acheong87] alias
alias ll=''\''ls'
```

I've tried putting the quotes in different places, to no avail. I've reduced the function to just the `echo`, and like in the `~/.bashrc`, it *looks* correct—so I can't figure out what hidden step is averting my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `eval` to achieve what you want:

```
function tailias
{
    eval $(echo "alias $1='${*:2}'" | tee -a ~/.bashrc)
}
```

This is better expained in this question (where an alternative solution is given)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079342/execute-command-containing-quotes-from-shell-variable

or directly in the bash FAQ:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Thanks! Could you perhaps explain why I'm seeing the behavior I'm seeing, however? Or, why `eval` fixes the problem? I'd like to understand the internals as much as I can.

Comment: Can you please expand this A so that it explains what you're doing a bit? Thanks.

Comment: Just found out a relevant question and added it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `eval` and `tee` to execute the command twice to add both a temporary `alias` and permanent `alias` in `~/.bashrc`, you can simply reload the `~/.bashrc` file after it is appended, which will update the alias list.

```
function tailias
{
    echo "alias $1='${*:2}'" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
}
```